# how to remove tuple in list into list of tuple in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, indexing, tuples

Here have list into list of tuples, need to remove repeating similar value in list.

list into list of tuple:

```
tup_list = [[('A', '10'), ('B', '28D'), ('C', '14'),('B','70F')], 
            [('B', '49C'), ('C', 'T26'), ('D', 'xyz')],
            [('A', '24K'), ('C', 'B28'), ('D', '54C')]]


new_lst = []
for tup_l in tup_list:
    new_tup_lst = []
    for tup in tup_l:
        if tup[0] not in new_tup_lst:
           new_tup_lst.append(tup)
    new_lst.append(new_tup_lst)
print(new_lst)
```

output is no changes can anyone correct the wrong please.

In first list of tuple there B's tuple is repeating two times. list should be contain only one B's tuple.

desired output:

```
[[('A', '10'), ('B', '28D'), ('C', '14')], 
[('B', '49C'), ('C', 'T26'), ('D', 'xyz')], 
[('A', '24K'), ('C', 'B28'), ('D', '54C')]]
```

Comment: Which value should be selected if there are multiple options? Also, please ask separate questions for separate issues.

Comment: Can you correct the code now please

Answer (score 0):

I get the expectation that you have when you are checking if a letter already exists in the new list. However, in this line

```py
if tup[0] not in new_tup_lst:
```

you are actually comparing a string `"B"` with a tuple `('B','70F')`. So, you will never be able to find a match.

I have a solution for you, but since I am kind of new to Python, this may not be the best or the most efficient solution:

```py
###
### Rest of the code
### 
    for tup in tup_l:
        # If there's is anything inside new_tup_lst, start comparing
        if new_tup_lst:

            # Letters will be stored here
            letters = []

            # For each element contained in new_tup_lst
            for element in new_tup_lst:

                # Get their letter and add it to letters list
                letters.append(element[0])

            # If the current tuples letter is not found in letters list
            if tup[0] not in letters:

               # Add the unique tuple to new_tup_lst
               new_tup_lst.append(tup)

        # If new_tup_lst is empty, just add the first element
        else:
            new_tup_lst.append(tup)
####
#### Rest of the code
####
```